# NHibernate - CreateSqlQuery returns only one row

Tags: nhibernate

I am new to nhibernate... i have created a an SQL query (hits an Oracle database), that returns custom result set like this...

[image]

I try to map these results into a custom object like this...(this object is not a persistant object and does not contain a nhibernate mapping file)
  [image]

The problem is that when i execute this sql query in the Oracle database it gives me all 4 records, however if when i execute this from the code , i get only one record (result as only one item).

Am i doing anythign wrong here?

Comment: sorry abt the formating...something got messed up

Answer (score 0):

Enable sql logging in NHibernate and check the question actually being executed.

Try [setting projections](http://www.junasoftware.com/blog/nhibernate-setresulttransformer-and-dto.aspx) so that transformer knows how to map the data.

Comment: Logged the sql and then extracted the sql from the log and executed it, still get the 4 record from in SQL Developer. But it only returns 1 result when run from the code. I dont think i can use projects, i am executing native sql#

Comment: You'll have to set them using `addScalar()` method call. You can check [documentation on NHForge](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#d0e10837).

Answer (score 0):

Its your Id column, well the lack of it! NHibernate cannot work out what is a unique row in your `ResultSet`. Therefore NHibernate only populates the first level cache once as it sees ALL four rows as duplicates.

You have two options:-

1. in your view return a unique id which is a unique Id although that judging by your schema that does not look possible **OR**
2. You need to override equals and GetHashCode in your view map class, see this blog[enter link description here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/anne_epstein/archive/2009/11/20/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.aspx) for more info.